# PHP List Users from SQL Database in Table

Tags: php, mysql

Hi so im trying to put all of the useres in a database, table into a html table this is what i have:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>UUID</th>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Access Key</th>
            <th>Phone Number</th>
            <th>Activated</th>
            <th>Role</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <?php
        include_once('inc/conf/databaseConnect.php');
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM list_users ORDER by id");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$row['uuid']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['firstname'].$rowtwo['lastname']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['email']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['security_key']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['phone_no']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['activated']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['role']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

This dosnt return anything, or any errors. It connects to the database correctly ive checked that its just not retrieving the users.

[Image of database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtxZV.png)

databaseConnect.php:

```
    <?php

//Create Connnection
$sqlLink = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'classified', 'user_details');

//If Error Connecting
if(!$sqlLink) {
    die('<center><br><h3>Error connecting to servers Database.');
}

?>
```

Comment: You don't actually check for errors. That may be why you don't see them.

Comment: apache logs the php errors to a file, and i chedk for errors in the db connect to make sure it connected properly and i use that dbconnect file for the login and edit details.

Comment: Does that query work on the db directly? Maybe the order by is incorrect and it should be `order by uuid`?

Comment: ive added an image of the database structure. uuid is their username e.g. "Joosh17"

Comment: `databaseConnect.php` is what we'd like to know is in there. `mysql_`? `mysqli_`? PDO?

Comment: and have a long hard look at `$rowtwo`.

Comment: I know that rowtwo part i noticed that when i posted it, and ive posted the databaseConnect.php code

Comment: Wow @Fred-ii- nice detecting. Josh, you need to use `mysqli` functions with a `mysqli` connection. `mysql_` functions are for a different, outdated/insecure, driver.

Comment: ahh, what functions do i use with mysqli

Comment: @chris85 My *Spidey sense* tingled.

Comment: Take a look at their manual there are all different ones you can use. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php (i prefer the prepare and execute). Then you need to update your fetch as well.

Comment: thanks @chris85 ive fixed it now (:

Comment: @chris85 OP has quite a few questions/answers with none accepted. Maybe that will show them how to properly close a question ;-) *Cheers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks. I have fixed the issue i updated to using mysqli's methods

```
<?php
include_once('inc/conf/databaseConnect.php');
$query = $sqlLink->query("SELECT * FROM list_users ORDER by id");
while($row = $query->fetch_array()){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['uuid']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['firstname'].$row['lastname']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['email']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['security_key']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['phone_no']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['activated']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['role']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

After seeing your edit because you did not [originally show](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33331430/1) us which connection method you were using; the almighty answer here (least the most important one) is that you can't mix different MySQL APIs.

- [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

You need to use the same one from connection to query.

Plus that `$rowtwo` should be `$row` as I stated in comments along with [my asking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33331430/php-list-users-from-sql-database-in-table#comment54459794_33331430) about what was inside your databaseConnect.php file.

Get to work with prepared statements also to help protect against an SQL injection.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Answer (score 0):

At least check for errors:

```
if ($query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM list_users ORDER by id");) {
  ...
} else {
  echo '<b>MySQL error:</b><br>' . mysql_error() . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Its not using the databaseConnect.php file because access denied.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysql_fetch_array` or fetch like this `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)`.

Comment: Why can't OP use `mysql_fetch_array`? This `mysql_fetch_array($query)` seems valid to me although gives back named and numerical references.

Comment: yeah off course it's return both type but, sometime it's changed pointer in array.